# Storing and extracting data in hashes with cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a lot of tests with different login credentials on cucumber/capybara/site_prism, which are quite messy. I want to unify them as much as possible; this solution seemed to be nice https://blog.jayway.com/2012/04/03/cucumber-data-driven-testing-tips/

But when following the example I run into this for the very first line of step definition

```
Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 2 arguments.
```

Apparently, I misunderstand how hashes should be handled; could somebody help please? My code with less test data is below
Cucumber

```
Given I login as "ad" with the following data:
    |role|usern       |userpass     |
    |ad  |adcccount   |adpassword   |
    |ml  |mlaccount   |mlpassword   |
```

step definition

```
Given /^I login as "(ad|ml)" with the following data:/ do |user|
 temp_hash = {}
    if (user == "ad")
      temp_hash = $ad
    elsif (user == "ml")
      temp_hash = $ml
    end

    usern = temp_hash["usern"]
    userpass = temp_hash["userpass"]

 @app = App.new
  @app.login.load
  @app.login.username.set usern
  @app.login.password.set userpass
  @app.login.btn_login.click
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because the second parameter being matched is the data_table.  Your step definition would need to be

```
Given /^I login as "(ad|ml)" with the following data:/ do |user, data_table|
  ...
```

If you look at the `Given /I create new user named "(user_1|user_2|user_3)" with the following data:/ do |user, data_table|` step in the article you linked you can see the same thing, although that doesn't use multiple entries in the data_table so I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Thomas; your hint lead to the following code that worked as expected

```
Given /^I login as "(ad|ml)" with the following data:/ do |login_role, data|

  temp_hash = {}
  data.hashes.each do |hash|
    if hash[:role] == login_role
      temp_hash[:role] = hash[:role]
      temp_hash[:usern] = hash[:usern]
      temp_hash[:userpass] = hash[:userpass]
    end
  end

    usern = temp_hash[:usern]
    userpass = temp_hash[:userpass]

  @app = App.new
  @app.login.load
  @app.login.username.set usern
  @app.login.password.set userpass
  @app.login.btn_login.click
  expect(@app.dashboard).to be_displayed
end
```